# How to restart the program to start over?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a card game.
Once the game is over, and I win or win the bank, I need the program to start again by pressing the "Restart" button.
I can't create the function that helps me do that.
I created the restart () function but the syntax is not correct and does not work.
How should I do this function so that the program starts again after pressing the button?
I show my code, I will continue testing and if I get it I will let you know
Thank you

```js
//CREACIÓN DE LA BARAJA
var carta = new Array(11);
var palos = new Array("Oros", "Bastos", "Copas", "Espadas");
var cartas_repe = new Array();
var puntos = 0;
var puntos_jugador, puntos_banca;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  carta[i] = palos;
}


//CARTA ALEATORIA

function aleatoria() {

  var num = parseInt((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var palo = parseInt(Math.random() * 4);
  var elegida = num + carta[num][palo];
  var selec;

  for (j = 0; j <= cartas_repe.length; j++) {

    selec = cartas_repe[j];

    while (selec == elegida) {

      num = parseInt((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      palo = parseInt(Math.random() * 4);

      elegida = num + carta[num][palo];
      j = -1;
    }
  }

  cartas_repe.push(elegida);

  document.getElementById("carta_jugador").src = "images/" + num + carta[num][palo] + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("carta_jugador").style.visibility = 'visible';

  if (num <= 7) {

    puntos = puntos + num;
  }
  else { puntos = puntos + 0.5; }

  if (puntos > 7.5) {

    puntos_jugador = puntos;
    document.getElementById("puntos").value = puntos;
    recuento();

  }
  else document.getElementById("puntos").value = puntos;

  document.getElementById("todas_cartas").innerHTML += "<img id='carta_jugador' alt='' src='images/" + num + carta[num][palo] + ".jpg' style='height: 97px; width: 66px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 4px;' />"

}

//FUNCION PLANTARSE

function plantarse() {
  document.getElementById("im_jugar").src = "images/trasera.jpg";
  document.getElementById("im_jugar").style.cursor = "default";
  document.getElementById("im_jugar").onclick = " ";
  puntos_jugador = puntos;
  puntos = 0;
  banca();
}

//FUNCION JUGAR BANCA

function banca() {

  var num = parseInt((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var palo = parseInt(Math.random() * 4);
  var elegida = num + carta[num][palo];
  var selec;

  for (j = 0; j <= cartas_repe.length; j++) {

    selec = cartas_repe[j];

    while (selec == elegida) {
      num = parseInt((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      palo = parseInt(Math.random() * 4);

      elegida = num + carta[num][palo];
      j = -1;
    }
  }

  cartas_repe.push(elegida);

  document.getElementById("carta_banca").src = "images/" + num + carta[num][palo] + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("carta_banca").style.visibility = 'visible';

  if (num <= 7) {
    puntos = puntos + num;
  }
  else { puntos = puntos + 0.5; }

  if (puntos > 7.5) {
    recuento();
    document.getElementById("puntos2").value = puntos;
    document.getElementById("todas_cartas_banca").innerHTML += "<img id='carta_banca' alt='' src='images/" + num + carta[num][palo] + ".jpg' style='height: 97px; width: 66px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 4px;' />"
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("puntos2").value = puntos;
    document.getElementById("todas_cartas_banca").innerHTML += "<img id='carta_banca' alt='' src='images/" + num + carta[num][palo] + ".jpg' style='height: 97px; width: 66px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 4px;' />"

    if (puntos <= puntos_jugador) {

      setTimeout("banca()", 1000);
    }
    else recuento();
  }
}

//RECUENTO
function recuento() {
  puntos_banca = puntos;

  if (puntos_banca > puntos_jugador && puntos_banca <= 7.5 || puntos_jugador > 7.5) {
    document.getElementById("texto").value = "GANA LA BANCA";

  }
  else if (puntos_jugador > puntos_banca && puntos_jugador <= 7.5 || puntos_banca > 7.5) {
    document.getElementById("texto").value = "HAS GANADO";

  }
  else if (puntos_jugador == puntos_banca) {
    document.getElementById("texto").value = "EMPATE";
  }

  bloquear();
}

//BLOQUEAR TODO
function bloquear() {

  document.getElementById("im_jugar").onclick = " ";
  document.getElementById("boton2").disabled = 'disabeled';
  document.getElementById("im_jugar").src = "images/trasera.jpg";
  document.getElementById("im_jugar").style.cursor = "default";
}

function reiniciar() {
  document.getElementById("reiniciar").onclick = aleatoria()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Juego de Cartas siete y media</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="height: 53px; margin-left: 180px; width: 1010px; margin-top: 0px;">

    <div style="float:left;width: 379px; height: 55px;">

      <p style="font-size: 25px; height: 34px; width: 300px; margin-left: 88px">
        <strong>Total Jugador: </strong>
        <input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="puntos" style="width: 45px; height: 28px; text-align:center;font-size: 20px;border-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" />
        <input id="boton2" type="button" value="Me planto" onclick="plantarse()" style="width: 76px; height: 32px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 6px;" />
      </p>

    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 505px; height: 56px;">

      <p style="font-size: 25px; height: 34px; width: 464px; margin-left: 4px">
        <input type="text" id="texto" value="7 y Medio" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0px; text-align:center; height: 31px; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: underline overline; margin-left: 9px;" /><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          Total Banca: </strong>
        <input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="puntos2" style="width: 45px; height: 28px; text-align:center;font-size: 20px;border-width: 0px;" />
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="contenedor_central" style="margin-left: 180px; margin-top:15px; height: 480px; width: 1009px;">
    <div id="juego_jugador" style="border: thin groove #C0C0C0; width: 500px; height: 437px; float:left;">
      <img id="im_jugar" onclick="aleatoria()" alt="Carta trasera" src="images/trasera_jug.jpg" style="height: 270px; width: 181px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 40px; cursor: pointer;" />
      <img id="carta_jugador" alt="" src="" style="height: 270px; width: 181px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 40px; visibility: hidden;" />
      <div id="todas_cartas" style="height: 122px; margin-left: 31px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="juego_banca" style="border-style: groove; border-width: thin thin thin 0px; border-color: #C0C0C0; width: 500px; height: 437px; float:left;">
      <img alt="Carta trasera" src="images/trasera.jpg" style="height: 270px; width: 181px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 40px;" />
      <img id="carta_banca" alt="" src="" style="height: 270px; width: 181px; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 40px; visibility: hidden;" />
      <div id="todas_cartas_banca" style="height: 122px; margin-left: 30px;"></div>
    </div>
    <center><button style="width: 224px;height: 23px;margin-top: 0px;margin-top:15px;" id="reiniciar" onclick="reiniciar()">Reiniciar</button></center>

  </div>
  <script src="js/sieteMedia.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it in a global while loop and monitor the game state.

Your states are :
0: before the game 
1: during the game
2: after the game

The core concept is called an event loop. I would suggest you to research in that direction.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your advice @dopamine, study some event loops, but I still don't know how to change the code. Should I put each part of my code in a loop? Any idea where to look for documentation to understand this? Thank you